# loadmovie into a fla-cs3 (as2)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs3

I've been trying to load a simple .swf (home.swf) and have it play automatically on my existing fla project (as2). These are the steps I have taken..

1) create MC, named "holder"
2) within first frame of MC, entered in.. loadMovie("home.swf","holder");

Nothing is showing, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  If you can help, I can send you the files I'm working with.  Am really stuck.. thanks.

Comment: are you creating the MC named "holder" programatically or is it already on the stage with the id of "holder"?

Comment: it's already on the stage.  So the only as2 script I have is the loadMovie("home.swf", "holder");

now should I be putting the as2 script on the MC or maybe on the frame that holds the MC?

Comment: try putting it on the frame with the MC and also have a stop(); statement...

Answer (score 0):

This works for CS3 (doc is here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/00001934.html#wp386574)

```
holder.loadMovie("home.swf");
```

Comment: tried that.. and still nothing is showing.  I'll attach the test file I'm working with.

http://rapidshare.com/files/337472757/test_test.zip.html

Comment: Brian, try Pindatjuh's suggestion but before that statement do a trace(holder) which will tell you what level the movieclip is on or perhaps whether the reference doesn't exist

Comment: tried tracing it... davidsleeps, if you don't mind would you email me at byee19@gmail.com.  I have the actual project where the real problem is happening.  The test_test environment is very artificial.

Answer (score 0):

is the path to the child swf correct?

in your example it would need to be in the same directory as your home.swf file, have you confirmed this (perhaps by running it from outside the Flash IDE)?